# TCPDF generate one PDF from multiple

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF class that extends TCPDF.  I need to create several PDFs so I then have individual PDF classes which extend PDF.  So for instance, I have something like this

```
class FirstPDF extends Pdf {
    ....code
}
class SecondPDF extends Pdf {
    ....code
}
```

Each of the PDF classes uses the Output function.  Everything works great, I can happily create my PDFs like so

```
$pdf = new FirstPDF($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4', $unicode=true, $encoding='UTF-8', $diskcache=false, $pdfa=false, $project);
$pdf->Output();

$pdf2 = new SecondPDF($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4', $unicode=true, $encoding='UTF-8', $diskcache=false, $pdfa=false, $project);
$pdf2->Output();
```

I now want to give the option to generate all PDFs within a single PDF.  The way I do it above produces separate PDF files.

Is there any way I can do this with TCPDF?

Thanks